# Can I change variable name inside a loop in Java

Tags: java, variables, dynamic-data, dynamic

I want to change the variable name with each iteration. Since the number of nodes created is dynamically changing.

I tried using one dimensional array but its returning a null pointer. My code is as follow

```
    GenericTreeNode<String> **root1[]** = null;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        String str="child"+i;
        System.out.println(str);

        **root1[i]** =new GenericTreeNode<String>(str);
    }
```

I am using already built datastructure

```
    public class GenericTree<T> {

private GenericTreeNode<T> root;

public GenericTree() {
    super();
}

public GenericTreeNode<T> getRoot() {
    return this.root;
}

public void setRoot(GenericTreeNode<T> root) {
    this.root = root;
}
```

Is there some other way in java or JSP to change the variable name dynamically inside the loop.

Comment: I have never seen a time when variable name changing is a good idea, nor do I think it possible, let alone in Java.

Comment: Of course it's a null pointer! What do you think `root1[] = null;` does? Anyway, besides being impossible, "change the variable name with each iteration" makes no sense. You should tell us what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can't do it. What's your real problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GenericTreeNode<String> root1[] = null;
```

This line is equivalent to this one:

```
GenericTreeNode<String>[] root1 = null;
```

so you create an array variable and initialize it to null

```
root1[i] =new GenericTreeNode<String>(str);
```

but here you assign a value to the array's index.

**This must throw a `NullPointerException`**!!.

Here's how to do it:

```
GenericTreeNode<String>[] root1 = new GenericTreeNode<String>[10];
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't change variable names in Java.

You got a NullPointerException when using an array because you tried to put a value in the array, and the array was null. You have to initialize the array, with the right number of elements :

```
int length = 10;
GenericTreeNode<String>[] root1 = new GenericTreeNode<String>[length];
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    String str = "child" + i;
    System.out.println(str);

    root1[i] = new GenericTreeNode<String>(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean to do this:

```
GenericTreeNode<String> root1[] = new GenericTreeNode<String>[10];
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    String str="child"+i;
    System.out.println(str);

    root1[i] = new GenericTreeNode<String>(str);
}
```

There's no need to "change a variable name".

Answer (score 1):

No, a variable name can't be changed. Try another method like a 2-dimensional array to create another "variable" as you're iterating.

Answer (score 1):

I not able to initiate GenericTree as array. Later I used just vector to solve the problem.